# How to disable counter cache in polymorphic has_one association on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations, has-one, counter-cache

I'm needing to disable counter cache for **has_one** associations as below and keep it just on has_many:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :email, as: :emailable
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :emails, as: :emailable
end

class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :emailable, polymorphic: true, counter_cache: emails_count
end
```

I don't have a **emails_count** column on **User** model. Any ideas?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify a counter_cache option, there should not be any counter caching, if caching happens regardless for you for some reason, you could try forcing a `counter_cache: false`

Comment: Hi Samer, in this case, I want caching only Company class and not User class, do you have any idea?

Comment: I don't think there is a clean way to do this, you could always monkeypatch your way to that though, I think if you override increment/decrement_counter methods on the User class you might get away with what you need here. If I were you though, I wouldn't use counter_cache at all, and would manually update the counters for Company whenever you add/delete emails.